# iMac display -- can't change screen brightness on bootcamp with Windows 7

Tags: imac, bootcamp, windows, display

I can't change iMac (2011) display brightness on bootcamp with Windows 7. When I press F1 it shows icon and even fill the bar, but nothing happen to display.

What have I tried:

- Reinstalling support files
- Installing fresh drivers from ATI site.
- Changing screen brigtness in windows "Power Options".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem, but I don't actually know what solved it:

- I rebooted manualy without any third-party software like **BootChamp**.
- I was pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> (option) key when booted.

Comment: I had the same issue, I was rebooting using command line from mac, because my option key was not working. But rebooting using another keyboard via Alt key worked.

Answer (score 0):

I just use the brightness keys on the Apple Bluetooth keyboard. But this is the only way that I know to adjust the brightness on my iMac when running Windows 8 bootcamp